# External images for WooCommerce Products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to import products to WooCommerce without
inserting the images but by linking from external url?

The imported products are affiliate products and its images
are often changed by the product vendors.

So it will be difficult for us to change product covers for around 
10,000 products occasionally when ever the product vendor changes it's images. So we think linking the image URL is ideal rather than importing physically.

We all know nothing is impossible, just want to know whether
it is an easy task.

Comment: also looking for this?